# How can I export an eclipse feature for multiple platforms?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-pde

I have an eclipse feature with a few platform dependent fragments (jogamp based plugins, to be precise)

I'd like to export that feature using PDE export. It works, as usual, only it will omit all plugins that do not match my current platform.

I want to use this exported feature as a p2 site that can be used from different platforms, so that's no good.

Is there a way to export an eclipse feature for all platforms?

Thanks, Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to get all the platforms from within eclipse as a PDE export.  I took a crack at using PDE build as a workspace export, http://pweclipse.blogspot.com/2011/02/pde-build-as-workspace-export.html but it requires some digging to get all the properties correct and it's specific to one workspace.

It's better to set up a proper headless PDE build to generate your p2 site.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll reserve some serious time to figure it out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: A PDE build project can contain a build.properties and a customTargets.xml from ECLIPSE_INSTALL/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.7.0.v20110512-1320/templates/headless-build directory, plus some map files.  See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_feature_build.htm and the Advanced Topics and p2 integration sections.